# ¿Qué verbo se debe usar para postularse a una oferta de trabajo? ¿"Aplicar"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, préstamo-lingüístico

Leo con frecuencia en las páginas de búsqueda de trabajo de España:

> Aplica a esta oferta de trabajo

Refiriéndose a entrar en el proceso de selección de esa posición. Al parecer, el verbo inglés *to apply* se ha ido colando en el castellano, tal y como recoge el diccionario de americanismos:

> [**aplicar**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=aplicar). (Del ingl. applicant).
>   I.  1.  intr. EU, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, RD, PR, Co, Bo; Ve, est. Solicitar alguien algo a través de un formulario escrito.
>   2.  tr. Ho, PR, Ec; Ve, est. Llenar alguien una solicitud.

¿Qué tan correcto es usar esta palabra en España? ¿Sería mejor utilizar algo así como *[postularse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tqj4Rok)* o simplemente hay que dejar pasar el tiempo hasta que la RAE acepte esta acepción?

Digo esto últimamente porque buscando en el [Mapa de diccionarios de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) me encontré con un caso parecido: *[nominar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QaWFrqX)*. Me sonaba que era incorrecto lo de "esta palabra está nominada a tres premios Oscar". Pero, oh sorpresa, desde 2001 hay dos acepciones nuevas:

> 2. tr. Designar a alguien para un cargo o cometido.
> 3. tr. Presentar o proponer a alguien para un premio

Que se suman a la existente desde 1780 de:

> 1. tr. Dar nombre a alguien o algo.

Por lo que sería una acepción presuntamente importada del inglés *nominate*.

Comment: En Colombia usamos también "presentarse a"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como puedes imaginar, la RAE [desaconseja ese uso](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=Aplicar) por ser un calco del inglés *apply*. El español tiene otras opciones bien arraigadas, como:

- *[**Apuntarse**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3LFQRl7) a una oferta de trabajo.* (Ver acepción 5.)
- *[**Inscribirse**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LjZ6dL7) en una oferta de trabajo.* (Ver acepción 2.)

Yo personalmente me decantaría por esta segunda opción.

Añadiendo un poco más de trasfondo, el Merriam-Webster explica que el verbo [*apply*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apply) significa:

> To ask formally for something (such as a job, admission to a school, a loan, etc.) usually in writing.

Es decir, hace hincapié en el hecho de que lo que haces es solicitar algo formalmente, normalmente mediante el rellenado de una solicitud. En español hacemos hincapié en que para dicho puesto va a haber muchos candidatos, y tu solicitud va a ser una más de las que compita por el puesto, de ahí que te tienes que inscribir en la oferta de trabajo (hacer que tu nombre figure entre otros con el fin de conseguir un empleo).

Curiosidad: hasta 1884, la palabra *inscribir* sólo tenía las acepciones de grabar letreros (en piedra, metal u otras materias), y de encerrar una figura geométrica dentro de otra. En dicho año se añadió la acepción que nos atañe.

Comment: Caramba, curioso lo de _inscribir_. Eso es que tenían pleno empleo y no había ofertas de trabajo :)

Answer (score 5):

Hay muchas variaciones regionales. En México por ejemplo es común usar el verbo `aplicar` para estos casos. Como menciona **Carlos Alejo** en su respuesta, probablemente por la influencia del inglés.

En Chile se usa `postular` y cualquier otro verbo no corresponde.

De la misma manera, hay países en los que se decanta por uno u otro verbo, los que en el fondo serían todos *"sinónimos"*, como `apuntarse`, `solicitar` o `inscribirse`.

Como tu pregunta hace referencia a la validez de uso particularmente en **España**, creo que incluso allí puede haber variaciones regionales.

En mi opinión, la palabra correcta es la que se determina por factores culturales y/o regionales. Es difícil que la RAE pueda abarcar todas estas diferencias, así que el hecho de que ellos digan que es incorrecta una u otra palabra, no implica que lo sea realmente en determinada región o país.

Lo más aconsejable es seguir la norma general de cada lugar. De todas maneras, creo que independiente de cuál palabra se use se entiende a qué se refiere, especialmente en el caso de extranjeros postulando/aplicando/solicitando/etc. (a) un trabajo se entiende que pueda usar una palabra distinta a la convencional. Independientemente de cuál verbo se use, creo que es fácil determinar la intencionalidad de la persona intentando conseguir el trabajo.

Comment: Interesante. _Postularse_ significa "proponerse para un cargo electivo", por lo que también podría servir, efectivamente. Las diferencias regionales simplemente hacen que el término suene raro (al menos a mí), pero no por ello deja de ser válido.